# HDMI TO SCART via VGA Converter (15KHz)

Tags: hdmi

I bought a HDMI / VGA Converter ... and a VGA to CGA Converter for 15Khz ... but now I want to plug in on my TV CRT ... but how to create a 5 PIN RGBs to SCART cable? Is there any schematics or something to help me to do this? When I use Composite output my playscreen is not fullscreen.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think this hardware question fits http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ better and might get better answers over there.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the longest and most complex route to get the Pi to display via SCART. There is a much easier route: get a composite cable (if you have a Pi A/B) or a 3.5mm to Composite cable (if you have a Pi A+/B+/2B) and a composite to SCART adapter. [Here is a post](http://purevirtual.eu/2013/07/15/installing-rasplex-on-a-raspberry-pi-scart-and-hdmi/) that shows how to use this (it's about installing Rasplex but ignore that part).

An example 3.5mm plug to composite cable is this one: [http://www.amazon.com/Parts-Express-3-5mm-Plug-Cable/dp/B0007V6JCK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007V6JCK)

and an example composite-to-SCART adapter is this one: [http://www.amazon.com/Scart-Composite-S-Video-Audio-Adapter/dp/B006RBMJ46](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006RBMJ46)

Comment: Ok thanks for your information but is output send 15Khz via this route or not ? That's the way I'm looking for to play Retro gaming ;) How do I set up my PI to output via Jack instead HDMI ?

Comment: That also only works if the SCART TV/monitor has composite in. If it is RGB only, you will get no picture.